# Starting Kibana roll up job

Tags: api, kibana-7

I have made a roll up job on the Kibana with the Kibana dev tool pictured below
[image: created roll up job]
I however have trouble starting this roll up job as I get following error below
[image: starting roll up job]

I'm following the documention found here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/rollup-start-job.html
I've had trouble with finding anyone else with this problem, do you have any ideas?

I use kibana version 7.1.1

Answer (score 1):

It should be a `POST` method.

**eg:** `POST _xpack/rollup/job/<job_id>/_start`

Also **There is no request body for the Start Job API.**

Please refer the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/rollup-start-job.html).

Comment: Thanks @ishara, however, I'm getting the same error using POST, and without using request body writing curl -X POST --.--.--.--:9200/etel_rollup-hourly/job/etel_hourly/_start gives me
{"error":"no handler found for uri [/etel_rollup-hourly/job/etel_hourly/_start] and method [POST]"}

Comment: @Mimeer it should be `curl -X POST --.--.--.--:9200/_xpack/rollup/job/etel_hourly/_start`  etel_hourly is the job_id

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Ishara. However, same error. for the documentation of 7.1 (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/rollup-start-job.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Ishara. I'm using the correct job id  now, However, same error. for the documentation of 7.1 (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/rollup-start-job.html) it has been simplified to POST _rollup/job/<job_id>/_start , which I have written as : ```curl -X POST --.--.--.--:9200/_rollup/job/etel_hourly/_start ```